# golang Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain

Tags: html, css, go, glide-golang

I have a problem in developing my webpage using golang.
server file (main.go):

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strings"
    "log"
)

type MyHandler struct {
}

func (this *MyHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    path := r.URL.Path[1:]
    log.Println(path)
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(string(path))

    if err == nil {
        var contentType string

        if strings.HasSuffix(path, ".css") {
            contentType = "text/css"
        } else if strings.HasSuffix(path, ".html") {
            contentType = "text/html"
        } else if strings.HasSuffix(path, ".js") {
            contentType = "application/javascript"
        } else if strings.HasSuffix(path, ".png") {
            contentType = "image/png"
        } else if strings.HasSuffix(path, ".svg") {
            contentType = "image/svg+xml"
        } else {
            contentType = "text/plain"
        }

        w.Header().Add("Content Type", contentType)
        w.Write(data)
    } else {
        w.WriteHeader(404)
        w.Write([]byte("404 Mi amigo - " + http.StatusText(404)))
    }
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", new(MyHandler))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

But when i type http://localhost:8080/templates/home.html
this what i see [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnqHs.png)
Why my page is not loaded right?? where is my css?? whyy is the error "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain:" appears while i have my content Type in main.go handled??

Comment: please click the link above to see what i see when opening my webpage ^

Comment: see also https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/HttpStaticFiles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your basic problem is very simple: You need `Content-Type` instead of `Content Type`.

However, there is a better way to match MIME types to file extensions in Go, specifically the [`mime`](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/) standard library package. I would strongly suggest that you use it.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by "Milo Christiansen" mime will help in this case.
I also wanted to point out that it will be efficient to use io.Copy instead of ioutil.ReadFile (if the stream copy can happen at kernel level it will do)

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "mime"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", ServeFile)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8400", nil))
}

func ServeFile(resp http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    path := filepath.Join("./resource/", req.URL.Path)
        
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(resp, err.Error(), http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }

    if contentType := mime.TypeByExtension(filepath.Ext(path)); len(contentType) > 0 {
        resp.Header().Add("Content-Type", contentType)
    }

    io.Copy(resp, file)
}
```